# Redshift: Finding first and last events in session without any session id

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift, self-join

I have a Redshift table of users' events in mobile-app:

```
|user|   screen   |collector_timestamp|
---------------------------------------
|1111| StartScreen|2018-10-01 07:02:33|
|1111|FinishScreen|2018-10-01 07:02:34|
|1112| OrderScreen|2018-10-01 07:10:33|
|1113| StartScreen|2018-10-01 09:01:27|
```

Session - it's a activity when interval between sequential events less than 1 hour.

I want to find a session (first and last `collector_timestamp`) in which user visits 0 or more any screens, then `StartScreen`, then 0 or more any screens, then `OrderScreen`, then 0 or more any screens, then `FinishScreen`.

When I try to apply triple self-join, I have an error with `permission denied to create temporary tables in database`, because the result of join's doesn't fir in memory.

How else I can found a suitable sessions?

Comment: Your question seems much broader than your title, so I'm confused about what you are asking.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I rewrote the title

Comment: Are there other possible values for "screen" besides StartScreen, FinishScreen and OrderScreen? I think you need to provide a larger example data set to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @Nathan Yes, there are other screens.

Answer (score 1):

Create session ids first using `LAG` window function in Redshift. 
Then aggregate the ordered events within a session, only using the screens you care about. Using this, you can filter for the exact pattern you're looking for. The example does this in one query, but it probably in practice should be done using multiple tables so you can reference the detailed data for each session. The following code builds a self contained example in Redshift using the data you provided, with some additional records to demonstrate results.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS events;
CREATE TABLE events
    ("user" INT
    , "screen" VARCHAR(12)
    , "collector_timestamp" TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO events
    ("user", "screen", "collector_timestamp")
VALUES
    (1111, 'StartScreen', '2018-10-01 07:02:33'),
    (1111, 'FinishScreen', '2018-10-01 07:02:34'),
    (1112, 'OrderScreen', '2018-10-01 07:10:33'),
    (1113, 'StartScreen', '2018-10-01 09:01:27'),
    (1112, 'StartScreen', '2018-10-01 09:10:33'),
    (1112, 'OrderScreen', '2018-10-01 09:11:33'),
    (1112, 'FinishScreen', '2018-10-01 09:12:33')
;

WITH sessionized_events AS(
  SELECT *
    , "user"||'_'|| SUM(new_session) OVER (PARTITION BY USER ORDER BY collector_timestamp ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS session_id
  FROM(
      SELECT 
          *
          , CASE
               WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM collector_timestamp) 
                       - LAG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM collector_timestamp))
                         OVER (PARTITION BY "user" ORDER BY collector_timestamp) >= 60 * 60
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END AS new_session
      FROM events
  ) s
)
SELECT 
    session_id
FROM sessionized_events
GROUP BY 1
HAVING listagg(DISTINCT screen)
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY collector_timestamp) like ('%StartScreen%OrderScreen%FinishScreen')
;
```

Results:

```
session_id
----------
1112_1
```

Postgres has a different syntax than Redshift, but for those without a Redshift cluster to run this on, I have an example on SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4e824/2).